# (MDM) - Android Remote Device management

Tags: android

I have an task to implement remote device management, The use case is Admin have take control over the enterprise based mobile devices, admin can able to delete all device data over remote(wipe out/lock the device) when the device stolen. I gone through that Android device management API, but I need of someone to elaborate the implementation procedure involved over this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android, you have to use Device Admin API's for lock device, remote wipe, set password, disable camera etc..
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html